# Python using pandas: how to Ignore delimiter within ""?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

My CSV files contains a header with 16 columns. The data lines contains 16 values separated with ",".

Just found that some lines contains values within `""` that contains `,`. This is confusing the parser. Instead of expecting 15 commas, it finds 18. One example below:

```
"23210","Cosmetic","Lancome","Eyes Virtuose Palette Makeup","**7,2g**","W","Decorative range","5x**1,2**g Eye Shadow + **1,2**g Powder","http://image.jpg","","3660732000104","","No","","1","1"
```

How can make the parser ignore the comma sign within `""`?

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas

csv1 = pandas.read_csv('Produktlista.csv', quoting=3)
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('Prislista.csv', quoting= 3)
merged = csv1.merge(csv2, on='id')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, quoting=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass param `quotechar='"'`. From the [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **quotechar** : str (length 1), optional
>
> The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.

e.g.:

```
In [9]:

t='''"23210","Cosmetic","Lancome","Eyes Virtuose Palette Makeup","7,2g","W","Decorative range","5x1,2g Eye Shadow + 1,2g Powder","http://image.jpg","","3660732000104","","No","","1","1"'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), quotechar='"', header=None)
df
Out[9]:
      0         1        2                             3     4  5   \
0  23210  Cosmetic  Lancome  Eyes Virtuose Palette Makeup  7,2g  W   

                 6                                7                 8   9   \
0  Decorative range  5x1,2g Eye Shadow + 1,2g Powder  http://image.jpg NaN   

              10  11  12  13  14  15  
0  3660732000104 NaN  No NaN   1   1
```

Comment: Great. Need some further help with io.iStringIO(). How can I read in my file "Produktlista.csv" into it? Tried with csv1 = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(Produktlista.csv), quotechar='"',quoting=3) and that obviously did not work. Excuse my ignorance, quite new to Python.

Comment: Ignore the stringio bit pass the path to your csv in its place

Comment: Tried it liked this csv1 = pandas.read_csv("Produktlista.csv", quotechar='"',quoting=3) as my original code. But I'm getting the following error   File "parser.pyx", line 607, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas\p
arser.c:6091)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Passed header=0 but only 0 lines in file

Comment: got to work, but pandas still complains on line like this "1256","EDT","Dolce & Gabbana","Light Blue","4,5ml","W","","","http://image.jpg","","737052074412","","No","","1","1"

Comment: I'm positive this is caused by the value "4,5ml". Shouldn't the argument quotechar='"' take care of that?

Comment: are you passing `quotechar='"'`?

Comment: Hi, that is correct: csv1 = pandas.read_csv('Produktlista.csv', quotechar='"',quoting=3)

Comment: I don't think you need the quoting=3 bit

Comment: Made the change and got the following instead:  File "hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
 (pandas\hashtable.c:11864)
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: EdChum: Is it possible to get in contact with you? I have a proposal that might interest you.

Comment: That error is an unrelated error which I have no context for as for proposals I don't think I have time to be honest, if it's a real job you may be better posting something on careers stack exchange