# How to read a csv file, which has double quotes next to commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that its rows look like this

`q4_1,"blabla,bla",new_label
 q4_2,alb,new_label2`

and I would like to read it in a `pandas` `data.frame` that will look like this

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['q4_1','q4_2'],
              'col2' : ['blabla,bla','alb'],
              'col3' : ['new_label','new_label2']})
```

Which parameter in the `pd.read_csv` function should I use for that ? I couldn't figure it out from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me it working nice with no parameter in pandas 0.23.4.

Comment: Pretty sure the `quotechar`-argument is what you're looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python using pandas: how to Ignore delimiter within ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914111/python-using-pandas-how-to-ignore-delimiter-within)

Comment: @jezrael I am also using pandas 0.23.4

Comment: @LukasThaler I have tried passing `quotechar='"'`(this is also the default value) but still doesnt work

Comment: `pd.read_csv(StringIO(your_data), names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])` works fine for me in pandas 0.22.0.

Comment: How are you reading this? you've mentioned it's a CSV file but the dataframe is created out of a dictionary in your question.
Can you share how you're trying to do it with the CSV and the error message you're getting? 
pandas will always read quoted characters as string so the " should disappear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

With **python 3.7** and **pandas 0.23.4**, worked this:

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=["col1", "col2", "col3"], squeeze=True)
```

the result is a DataFrame with the structure described in the question:

```
    col1        col2        col3
 0  q4_1  blabla,bla   new_label
 1  q4_2         alb  new_label2
```